# Sorting Datatable with linq with correct datatype of a column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

hello I have this code that use to sort a datatable.

```
    Dim sortingIndex As Integer = orderby

    Dim DataTableNew As DataTable = New DataTable
    DataTableNew = dt.Clone

    Dim query = (From c In dt.AsEnumerable Order By c.Field(Of String)(sortingIndex) Ascending)
    query.CopyToDataTable(DataTableNew, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)
```

My problem is that with this method I always need (Of String) for it to work, so the date columns are also managed as Strings witch is the problem. Is there a way to use the correct type so the sorting is based on the type of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq rocks, but sometimes the [good old methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are better. You can do

```
dt.Select(string.Empty,dt.Columns[sortingIndex].ColumnName)
```

It sorts the DataTable using the column's data type.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I can't figure out how to embed this , can you give me an example based on my previous code?

Comment: `var DataTableNew = dt.Select(string.Empty...` should do.

Comment: and what if I need descending or ascending sorting? how can I manipulate that?

Comment: For descending, add ` DESC` to the column name, see the link I supplied.

Comment: oh, I missed the link you posted. Thank you